# i can't find it in quick fix (reduce is not difined) how fix this

Tags: python

```
def sumall(nm1, nm2) :
    return nm1 + nm2 

mynumber = [1, 5, 7, 9, 15, 130]
result = reduce(sumall, mynumber)
```

And this is the result in terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\python\built_in_function6.py", line 25, in <module>
    new_func(sumall, mynumber)
  File "g:\python\built_in_function6.py", line 23, in new_func
    result = reduce(sumall, mynumber)
NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the reduce function from the functools module.

```py
from functools import reduce
```

And it will work.